# Can I build a dll/so with combination of C and C++ files?

Tags: c++, c

I have some legacy code built in C, and now I want to introduce a new source file in the same dll project using C++ as the language. How can I do  this?

Comment: please clarify: you want to reuse at binary level? and you want to use c++ from c or vice-versa?

Comment: I have a dll with 2 .C file, now I want to add a new CPP file in this dll. Will this work? So I am final DLL will have 2 .C file and 1 .CPP file